# How to perform function in .exe file using a C# application

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, zebra-printers

I have a C# application in which it does some basic printing options to Zebraprinets. 
In my application i am opening the **.net paint** using the C# application. **By using .net paint i need to convert the a .jpeg file to pcx format**. I am using it now manually..
So my real question is, can i perform all these actions from my C# application. i want my application to perform the functions of .net paints

For example. after opening the .net paint. I want to import the file using `Open + O`..Select file from folder `@c:\users\user\sample.jpeg` then in .net paint perform the functions `(ctrl + Shift + L)` then `(ctrl + Shift + G)`. After all these save `ctrl + Shift + S` in location `C:\out\`.

Can i do this.
Please let me know.

code snippet:-

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        string filename = "";

        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            filename = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(ofd.FileName);
        }
       // MessageBox.Show(filename, "file");
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = filename;
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;

        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you wish to continue?", "Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Paint.NET\PaintDotNet.exe");
           // here i need to perform the function like
           //Open + O`
           //ctrl + Shift + L)` then `
           //(ctrl + Shift + G)`. then save 
           //`ctrl + Shift + S`
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you use a library such as https://pdnbulkupdater.codeplex.com/documentation

Comment: @Jack i have gone through this already.. this is for iPhone app. I need covers of file from bmp to pcx

Comment: So are you basically just trying to convert an image from one type to another? (jpeg to pcx) so the Zebra Printer can recognize the specific image format for output?

Comment: @DRapp yes exactly..

Comment: Which Zebra printer model are you using, and what reporting method... are you doing direct ZPL (Zebra Printer Language) and sending the feed through COM, or using windows drivers and a C# .rdlc file?

Comment: @DRapp we are using zebra printer 105S. i am using C# application to make all the buttons and stuffs. But the communication is done through ZPL `s += "^FO184,155^A0N,47,36^FD" + txtBox.Text + "^FS^XZ";` using comm port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just reference the Paint.NET assemblies directly and use a surprising amount of its functionality that way. I don't know about the API you are referring to specifically but I have used it in the past to generate sprites from .pdn files in a compile pipeline.

Try adding a reference to these assemblies: `C:\Program Files\Paint.NET\PaintDotNet.*.dll` Then poke around the classes in those namespaces.

Comment: can you tell me any references

Comment: Just look at the files in that folder. For example `PaintDotNet.Core.dll`. All of the dll's in there starting with PaintDotNet can be referenced and used directly.

Comment: but i cant read.. it..When i opened throught the notepad++ i am seeing this <https://imageshack.com/i/id9b4SVoj>. How to use these.. I have no idea

Answer (score 3):

You can go and download [Magick.NET](http://magick.codeplex.com/). It is a .NET graphics manipulation library that supports [over 100 image formats](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/formats.php) including PCX. From their website, here is [an example](http://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Convert%20image&referringTitle=Documentation) of how to convert one image format to another.

**EDIT**

Here is an example to convert a jpeg to a pcx:

```
using ImageMagick;
namespace JpegToPcx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("MyFile.jpeg"))
            {
                image.Write("MyFile.pcx");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @but simple wether it will convert or nor.. i just went to your example.. can i substitute the .jpeg to .bmp and rgb to .grf will it work.. or can you help me a bit more

Comment: @StacyKebler - I just added an example. It should be that easy to do.